# How to match both .ASM and .S in Emacs regular expression for auto-mode-alist?

Tags: regex, emacs

> How to match both .ASM and .S in Emacs regular expression for auto-mode-alist?

I've tried to write a regular expression as below, but it doesn't work, i.e. .asm and .s files are not recognized as belonging to nasm-mode.

```
(require 'nasm-mode)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.\(ASM\)\|S\\'" . nasm-mode))
```

However, the simplified version matching only .asm works just fine:

```
(require 'nasm-mode)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.ASM\\'" . nasm-mode))
```

Also, why do I use uppercase characters? (I've followed the description in nasm-mode.el).

Comment: Try `"\\.\\(ASM\\|S\\)\\'"` to match a `.` that is followed with either `ASM` or `S`.

Answer (score 1):

Direct answer to the question (always use double `\`, as string interpretation "uses" the first and regex code the second):

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.\\(ASM\\|S\\)\\'" . nasm-mode))
```

Alternative way I would use

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.ASM\\'" . nasm-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.S\\'" . nasm-mode))
```

Comment: Also, why do I use uppercase characters, when the file extension is really .asm or .s?

Answer (score 1):

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist `(,(concat (regexp-opt '(".ASM" ".S")) "\\'") . nasm-mode))
```

`regexp-opt` takes a list of strings (not regexps), and builds a regexp that matches any of those strings.  It's kind of overkill here, but it's great for matching longer lists of strings.